# How make input element take up available space next to a fixed width element?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bear of a time getting the following to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/1bq55L65/

I have a `div` element `container`, which needs to take up 100% of the available space of its parent. Then, inside it, I have a fixed-width element that needs to be pegged to the right. The remaining space to the left of the fixed-width element is to be filled with an `input` text field.

My understanding is that when I set the width of an element to 100%, it computes the actual width in pixels based on the width of its parent element (in this case, the `div` called `expanding`). The behaviour I'm seeing, however, seems to indicate it takes the width of the parent's parent (i.e. `container`)

Bonus question: how can I get the *height* of the fixed element to be the same height as the `div` it's contained in (i.e. `container`).

In either case, I'd rather avoid script if at all possible. It seems this should be a common enough requirement that CSS should accomplish it straight away.

Assume recent browsers, and in particular IE9 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width is relative to the parent. The parent of the `input` is a `div` and by default `div`s are block level elements, with width 100%) so as the div is 100% of it's container (the `#container` div). The floating element `#fixed` has no influence on the width of `#expanding` in this situation.

Use a table layout or calculate the remaining space using `calc`:

```css
#container {
    background-color:pink;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:60px
}

#fixed {
    width: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    background-color: #FFEEEE;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#expanding {
    background-color:#FFDDDD
}

#inputField {
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% - 70px);
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="fixed">Fixed</div>
    <div id="expanding">
       <input id="inputField" type="text" value="Type here" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearly since by default `input` has some UA styles you'll need to either reset these or take them in consideration (also `calc` needs to be supported by the browsers you're targeting, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)..

Comment: Good answer. Just a note though - calc doesn't have great support on Android or older versions of IE (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Comment: @AndyFurniss I was just looking at `calc` support and considering an alternative option with `flexboxes`

Comment: `calc` has better support than `flexbox`  on ie , so I'd go with that

Comment: Could either of you comment on why the `input` in the original sample appears to take its 100% width from the `container` element (i.e. its grandparent)? That's what's been making my head ache. I was expecting it to take its width from the `expanding` div, which should eat all space except that space taken up by the floating `fixed` div, in my (granted, limited) understanding.

Comment: Agreed. Wasn't saying it was a bad option! Just noting as I'm unaware of John's target browsers.

Comment: @AndyFurniss also  display:table looks good (like your answer)

Comment: @JohnKällén - width is relative to the parent. The parent of the input is a div and by default divs are block level elements (ie. width 100%) so as the div is 100% of it's container (the #container div) then the input with be 100% of the container also. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AndyFurniss: to be clear, the width calculation for the block div `expanding` will completely disregard the presence of the floating div `fixed` in this case?

Comment: @JohnKällén Yes because `#expanding`s parent is `#container` and the `#fixed` has no influence on the width of `#expanding` in this situation. Using a table layout or calculating the remiaining space (using calc, like in maioman's andswer) fixes this.

Comment: @JohnKällén take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/1bq55L65/2/ hope this clarify's the concept of relativeWidths

Comment: @maioman: could I prevail on you to add the explanation that Andy provided to your answer, or would you rather have me edit your answer, before I mark it as "the" answer?

Comment: Wish I could award you both with the answer credit -- I went with the calc version as it simpler for me to implement, not necessarily for its technical merit. Help much appreciated, sanity restored!

Answer (score 2):

Using `display:table` could be of use here. I find it's a good way of 'filling the remaining space'. How's this?

```css
#container {
    display:table;
    background-color:pink;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:60px
}

#fixed {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #FFEEEE;
    height:100%;
}

#expanding {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#FFDDDD
}

#inputField {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="expanding">
       <input id="inputField" type="text" value="Type here" />
    </div>
    <div id="fixed">Fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution puts the `fixed` element to the left; the intent is to have it pegged to the right.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet? It's on the right. Note that I removed the `float:right` from the fixed element.

Comment: Weird; I copied your snippet to the original fiddle, and it was incorrectly aligned. Will try this on my website and get back to you.